# Can I tell IE9 to launch with the IE8 or IE7 rendering engine

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-7

I'm setting up a testing machine that needs to launch multiple copies of IE when the machine boots, because the browser will be running automated tests. I know IE9 can render IE7 and IE8 but is there a way to launch the browser into these modes when it starts?

I had a look at the command line options but couldn't find anything. I'd also prefer not to use VHD's.

Comment: In case it helps: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: I used to use IETester but it doesn't render correctly and crashes heaps.